# "Snap" to int values for width/height when resizing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe

I have a JFrame that contains a custom JComponent that displays a grid with a fix amount of rows and columns. When the JFrame is resized, the spacing between lines is recalculated so that the grid increases in size while still keeping the same amount of elements. The issue comes when resizing to a height or width that is to large to fit n columns (or rows) but too small to fit n+1. Here's the correct view:

[image: Alignment is ok here]

You can see the blue lines perfectly align with the black line on the right. If I increase the width of the window, I get the following problem:[image: Extra spacing after the last blue line]

The grid extends JComponent, and in its `paintComponent` I do the following:

```
// Get the size of the JFrame containing the Grid
Dimension df = getParent().getSize();

// Calculate spacing between vertical lines (20 = number of vertical lines)
int vert_spacing = (df.width - 2 * this.margin) / 20;

// Draw the black border
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawRect(this.margin, this.margin, df.width - 2 * this.margin, df.height - 2 * this.margin);

// Draw vertical lines
for (int i = this.margin; i <= df.width - this.margin; i += vert_spacing) {
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawLine(i, this.margin, i, df.height - this.margin);
}
```

A solution I thought of would be to "snap" to a good value after the JFrame is resized, but I haven't been able to get that to work and I'm not sure if it's the best solution. The issue is with the fact that `drawLine` takes `int`s as its values so the spacing between lines gets rounded up/down. Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a `ComponentListener` when the frame is resized, set the size to the closest of the "snaps".

Comment: @screenmutt: What I'm noticing is that setting the size in a `componentResized` component listener gets messy because it fires even if the mouse is still "clicked" and then the outside border (from the OS' GUI) will stay where the mouse is while the inner window will be resized. I feel like using drawLine with non-`int` values would work a lot better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are painting the rectangle too large. You need to take into account that the rectangle size should be based on the vertical spacing * 20 and not the actual size of the parent window.

Maybe something like:

```
int vert_spacing = (df.width - 2 * this.margin) / 20;
int extraSpace = df.width - (vert_spacing * 20);

// Draw the black border
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawRect(this.margin, this.margin, (df.width - extraSpace) - 2 * this.margin, df.height - 2 * this.margin);
```

Now of course the above solution will be skewed to the left so you may also want to center your grid in the space available. So in addition to using your margin as the X offset you would need to use half of the extra space:

```
int vert_spacing = (df.width - 2 * this.margin) / 20;
int extraSpace = df.width - (vert_spacing * 20);
int xOffset = extraSpace / 2;

// Draw the black border
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawRect(this.margin + xOffset, this.margin, (df.width - extraSpace) - 2 * this.margin, df.height - 2 * this.margin);
```

Of course you would also need to use the xOffset when drawing the vertical lines.

Answer (score 0):

You should work with floating coordinates and then round them just in order to get the integers required by the "draw" function:

```
// Calculate spacing between vertical lines (20 = number of vertical lines)
float vert_spacing = (float)(df.width - 2 * this.margin) / 20f;

// Draw vertical lines
for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
    int x = Math.round(this.margin + i*vert_spacing);
   g.setColor(Color.blue);
   g.drawLine(x, this.margin, x, df.height - this.margin);
}
```